# Jenkins Build Status

Tags: powershell, jenkins, github, servicenow

I have a Jenkins Job which passes variables/parameters to a powershell script.
Once the job completes I either get:-

Finished: SUCCESS

Finished: FAILURE

I want to be able to send the result of the job to ServiceNow to close the associated task.  I have the URL string needed to pass the information back to Service Now however, I do not know how to reference the Build Status from the Jenkins job.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you using declarative or scripted pipeline?

Comment: So I am not really using a pipeline as such, building with parameters which can either be passed from ServiceNow or manually in Jenkins. 
Once the job runs there is only a need to pass status back to Service Now, no other job needs to kick off

Comment: Are you using free style project? Send the status to ServiceNow could be the end step of your script.

Comment: Yes I am using a Freestyle project.  The issue is I am unsure on how to capture the status.  
My build calls a PowerShell Script, I have tried setting up a conditional step to catch Success / Failure after the Powershell script runs however this only seems to kick in if the script was successful.  
If my PowerShell script fails it never gets to the conditional step for Failure and so I am unsure on how to capture this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can get the build status is by the currentbuild object and get the currentStatus 
You can check in your pipeline syntax -> global variables. 
You could also access this https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getResult--

Comment: Thanks for this and sorry but I am not sure where I would run this.  My build calls a powershell script (saved in Github).  Would I run this code after I call the script but still within the Powershell Command window or would I run as a post-build action?

Comment: Then you could use the Jenkins api to get the status of the present build by generating the url with the env variables that jenkins provides.